# How to access data in my code? - variable might have not been initialised

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors

I am having some problem reading the value ba,fr,lit and mid. May I know how should I resolve it. I tried declaring them as global variables but it was to no avail. Kindly help thanks, below is the code, the error occurs on this line ( fileout.println(m + " , " + l + " , " + s + " , " + u + " , " + ba + " , " + " , " + fr + " , " + lit + " , " + mid );)

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String m = model.getText();
        String l = line.getText();
        String s = shift.getText();
        String u = unitno.getText();
        String ba;
        String fr;
        String lit;
        String mid;
        try{
             Double b = Double.parseDouble(back.getText());
             if(b<350 || b>625){
                  back.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                  back.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                 int dialogButton = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;
                 int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "The value that you have entered is not within the range of 350 to 625. Press yes to save anyway and cancel to edit.", "Error", dialogButton);
                 if(dialogResult ==0){
                      ba = back.getText();
                 }
             }
             else{
                   ba = back.getText();
                  back.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                  back.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
             }
        }catch(NumberFormatException  nfe){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please ensure that it is in integer.");
            back.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
            back.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        }
         try{
             Double f = Double.parseDouble(front.getText());
             if(f<350 || f>625){
                  front.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                  front.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                 int dialogButton = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;
                 int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "The value that you have entered is not within the range of 350 to 625. Press yes to save anyway and cancel to edit.", "Error", dialogButton);
                 if(dialogResult ==0){
                      fr = front.getText();
                 }
             }
             else{
                   fr = front.getText();
                  front.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                  front.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
             }
        }catch(NumberFormatException  nfe){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please ensure that it is in integer.");
            front.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
            front.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        }
           try{
            Double li = Double.parseDouble(little.getText());
             if(li<0.8 || li>3.4){
                  little.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                  little.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                 int dialogButton = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;
                 int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "The value that you have entered is not within the range of 0.8 to 3.4. Press yes to save anyway and cancel to edit.", "Error", dialogButton);
                 if(dialogResult ==0){
                      lit = little.getText();
                 }
             }
             else{
                   lit = little.getText();
                  little.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                  little.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
             }
        }catch(NumberFormatException  nfe){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please ensure that it is in integer.");
            little.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
            little.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        }
           try{
            Double mi = Double.parseDouble(middle.getText());
             if(mi<0.8 || mi>3.4){
                  middle.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                  middle.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                 int dialogButton = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;
                 int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "The value that you have entered is not within the range of 0.8 to 3.4. Press yes to save anyway and cancel to edit.", "Error", dialogButton);
                 if(dialogResult ==0){
                      mid = middle.getText();
                 }
             }
             else{
                   mid = middle.getText();
                  middle.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                  middle.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
             }
        }catch(NumberFormatException  nfe){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please ensure that it is in integer.");
            middle.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
            middle.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        }
            BufferedWriter output = null;
         FileInputStream fs = null;
         FileWriter fout = null;
        try {
            // TODO add your handling code here:

            File myFile = new File("C:/Users/kai/Desktop/capforce.txt");
            if(!myFile.exists()) {
                myFile.createNewFile();
            } 
            fs = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/kai/Desktop/capforce.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));
            output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(myFile,true));
            PrintWriter fileout = new PrintWriter(output,true);
            if (br.readLine() == null) {
                   fileout.println("Model" + " " + "Date" + " " + " " + "Line" + " " + "Shift" + " " + "Unit Number" + " "+ "Capped Force - Capped Z1 (Back)" + " " + "Capped Force - Capped Z1 (front)" + " " +"Wiper to pen interference Z(Little man)" + " " + "Wiper to pen interference Z(Middle man)" );
             }
            for(int i = 1; i<100; ++i){
                String line = br.readLine();
                if(line==null){
                   fileout.println(m + " , " + l + " , " + s + " , " + u + " , " + ba + " , " + " , " + fr + " , " + lit + " , " + mid );
                   break;
                }
            }        
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(setup.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                output.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(setup.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

       this.dispose();
    }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: variable might have not been initialised

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize all variables:

```
    String ba = null;
    String fr = null;
    String lit = null;
    String mid = null;
```

Comment: Hold on, one more question. Why isn't my answer from  ba = back.getText() passed into ba?

Comment: If you have another question, [ask another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: It's the same question.